# Разыменование указателя на тип void в С

Tags: c, указатели

Я написал простенькую программу воспроизводящую поведение библиотечной функции memchr (The  memchr()  function scans the initial n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s for the first instance of c.)
При компиляции компилятор жалуется на эту строчку <return ((unsigned char*)(s[i]));> что я пытаюсь разыменовать указатель на **void**. Но я не понимаю почему - ведь я уже привел тип **void** к типу **unsigned char***...
Если я пишу так: <return ((unsigned char*)(s + i));> то все работает. Объяните пожалуйста почему?

```
void    *ft_memchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;
    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        if (((unsigned char*)s)[i] == (unsigned char)c)
            return ((unsigned char*)(s[i]));
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

    char* ptr = ft_memchr(str, 'c', 4);
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("none");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("%c\n", ptr[0]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Обычно в функциях подобного типа (с аргументом `void *`) лучше завести указатель нужного типа и присвоить ему аргумент, а дальше уже писать все с типизированным указателем. Т.е. `void * foo(void *mem, ...) { unsigned char *s = (__typeof__(s))mem; ... }` // Кстати, вместо этого -- `return ((unsigned char*)(s[i]));` правильно будет просто `return s + i;`

Comment: И еще. Вы сами пишете такие функции или изучаете чужие? Если изучаете, то лучше посмотрите [вот на это](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ай-я-яй! Ваша функция возвращает `void*`, не `const void*`, а это нехорошо... Z-то вы указатель на `const`!

Словом, как-то так - при вольностях С с типами - вполне работает:

```
const void *ft_memchr(const void *ss, int c, size_t n)
{
    const unsigned char * s = ss;
    for(size_t i = 0; i<n; ++i)
        if (s[i] == (unsigned char)c) return s+i;
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return ((unsigned char*)(s[i]));
```

индексация `[ i ]` : `void *` типа не будет работать, так как размер типа неизвестен.

Сначала нужно привести тип указателя на тип известного размера.

А так как вам нужно возвращать указатель, то можно так :

```
return (unsigned char*)s + i ;
```

или

```
return & ((unsigned char*)s)[i] ;
```

*И не забывать, что у вас аргумент константный, и нужно вернуть указатель тоже константный.*

```
void const   *ft_memchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n)
..
char const * ptr = ft_memchr(str, 'c', 4);
```